# VBA code too slow - takes 6 hours to execute output

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lengthy code unable to share the 8000+ liner code completely, The code runs through loops multiple times row by row, if there are 10000+ rows then loop runs 10000+ times.

Since the code is too lengthy I am sharing a part of it were I feel it can shorten the time taken, But I am missing a loop in it and how do I include that Is my query for now.

I’ll be sharing the original code and very next is the replacement code kindly check and let me know we’re and how to include.

Original code:

```
For i = 2 To endlineMM

     If worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(I,9).value = “registered locked” or worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,9).value = “registered unlocked” Then

 For j = 3 to endlineDHDO

If instr(Lcase(worksheets(“DHDO”).cells(j,2).value),Lcase(Worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,2).value)) <> 0 Then
    If Lcase(Worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,2).value) = Lcase(worksheets(“DHDO”).cells(j,2).value) Then
    Found missing = True
    Exit For

Else if j= EndlineDHDO And Lcase(Worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,2).value)<>
Lcase(worksheets(“DHDO”).cells(j,2).value) Then

  Foundmissing = false
 End if
Next j
If foundmissing = False Then

Etc......
```

Replacement code:

```
For i = 2 to endlineMM

If worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(I,9).value = “registered locked” or worksheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,9).value = “registered unlocked” Then

 Test_ID = Worlsheets(“MM Source”).cells(i,2).value

 With sheets(“DHDO”).Range(“B:B“)
Set prg = .Find(Test_ID, LookIn:=xlvalues)

 If prg is nothing then
Foundmissing =true
Exit for
Else
Foundmissing = false
End if
End with

If foundmissing = false Then

Etc......
```

If you observe above from original code it has “i“ as well as “j” but in replacement code I am missing “j”

How can I fix my Replacement code

let me know how to edit the Replacement code please

Comment: Since you do not iterate anymore, no need of `j`, I would say... But you must put your `Find` in a loop, followed by `FindNext`. Putting the first occurrence address in a string |(`InitialAddress`)variable and exit the loop when the FindNext address is = InitialAddress.

Comment: Hi Pete can you please share by editing the above paragraph I.e, replacement code

Comment: I am not completely following your question. The original is fast and the replacement code isnt?

Comment: I have shared A sub module, part of the code So the Original code takes 1 hour to execute and replacement code takes few seconds but my numbers are not matching, I felt I’m making a mistake in the replacement code

Comment: And how is endlineMM defined?

Comment: EndlineMM were “MM Source“ is a sheet name similarly EndlineDHDO were “DHDO” is the sheet name and the DHDO sheet has Raw data

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to indicate the behavior that you would like to occur. It's hard to figure out what your goals are. From reviewing the first block of code, it seems that `FoundMissing` is set to true when the value is found. In the second block of code, `FoundMissing` is set to true when `prg` is nothing, which means the value was not found. Perhaps this is part of the problem?

Comment: I would like to share the complete script, so that we are on the same page. Can you suggest me an alternate please.  As I am typing the code can’t copy And share the code due to restrictions

Comment: Your fist step could be to filter in place of the first loop, then loop through visible cells after, could save a ton of loops.

Comment: You might find it incomplete oz I am jus sharing part of code and there is no connection for you to get a clarity

Comment: @davesexcel can u show with an example from my code or any alternative will be helpful

Comment: Consistent indention will always make your code easier to read. [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features#SmartIndenter)* is a VBIDE plugin that has (with permission) rewritten the original Smart Indenter code to make it (along with a plethora of other tools) available within the VBIDE. *Big fan, consistent user, "official" tester, occasional contributor.

Comment: Use variables for your worksheets so they only have to be resolved once.  Dim wksMMS as WorkSheet; Set wksMMS = worksheets(“MM Source”) ; TestID = wksmms.cells... etc.

Comment: It would really help to explain exactly what the snippet is doing - without the context of the larger code it's difficult to figure out the best way to rewrite it.  For example if you just need to check for an exact match In ColB then Match() is very fast (faster than Find() for example)

Comment: I agree. I’ll share the complete code please take time to read through the code and suggest

Comment: Still waiting for the code

Comment: Hello @Davesexcel  sorry for late reply, when I try to paste the code it does not fit the bandwidth as it is more than 30000 lines which included all sub modules and the main code, any suggestion please

Comment: Did you test out the code I supplied for filtering first to reduce the loops?

Comment: Hello, yes I didi’s try but to keep you posted there are 5 hidden sheets like MM Source is one sheet there are 5 more sheets, can I copy the same code to others by replacing MM with other sheet names. As I have shared above Original code it has “For j = 3 .... to last before line “next j” can I replace the code there for all sheets one below the other

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your code will run a lot faster if you use Ranges and Arrays rather than individual Cells.

For example, if you were to take a spreadsheet and fill columns A1:B10000, with numeric data, and then compare the performance of the two following codes:

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim output(10000) As Double
Dim i As Integer

data = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1", "B10000")))

For i = 1 To 10000
    output(i - 1) = data(i, 1) + data(i, 2)
Next
Range("C1", "C10000").Value = Application.Transpose(output)
```

and

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10000
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
Next
```

You will notice that the first variation is considerably faster.

By way of explanation Application.Transpose is necessary to assign the range to an array.  It needs to be doubled in the first case, because it is a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that will filter the MM Source sheet, then loop through the visible cells finding cells in DHDO sheet

```
Sub Do_It()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim a As Range
    
    Set sh = Sheets("MM Source")
    Set ws = Sheets("DHDO")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With sh
        Set rng = .Range("I2:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        .Columns("I:I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                                   "=registered locked", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=registered unlocked"
        
        For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
            
            Set a = ws.Range("B:B").Find(c.Offset(, -7), LookIn:=xlValues)
            
            If Not a Is Nothing Then
                'MsgBox "Do nothing"
            Else
                'MsgBox "Do something"
                c.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
            
        Next c
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```